Euler characteristic and Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch
Let X be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Write $c(X) = 1 + x$, where $c_1(X)=x$. Then
\begin{align*} \chi(X) & = \int_X c_{top} (X) \\
&= \int_X c_1(X)
\end{align*}
since $c_1(X) = c_{top} X$. Then
$$td(X) = \frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} = 1 + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{12} + \dots $$
gives $td(X) = 1 + \frac{x}{2}$ since X is 1-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$. Now by Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch,
\begin{align*}
\chi(X) &= \int_X ch(X) \wedge td(X) \\
&= \int_X (1 + x)(1 + \frac{x}{2} ) \\
&= \int_X \frac{3}{2} x
\\
&= \frac{3}{2} \int_X c_1(X)
\end{align*}
so $ \int_X c_1(X) = \frac{3}{2} \int_X c_1(X) $ implies $ \int_X c_1(X) = 0$.
Where have I gone wrong?

You are misinterpreting the left-hand side. This is the sheaf Euler characteristic (here $h^0-h^1$), not the topological Euler characteristic. And this is Hirzebruch-R-R, no?

The Mirror Symmetry textbook lists this as Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch.

$ch(X)=ch(TX)=e^x=1+x$ here, no?

@locallytrivial The Mirror Symmetry textbook is mistaken. See Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch vs Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch. Grothendieck's version is a generalisation, proved three years after Hirzebruch's proof.
